# Como posso copiar uma imagem para a área de transferência (Clipboard)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão, área-de-transferência

Estou utilizando este comando para capturar a tela.

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function (image) {
    // image = base64;string
});
```

E agora gostaria de copiar a imagem capturada para área de transferência (Clipboard).

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 6):

Eu precisei fazer algo assim em um passado recente e também não consegui chegar em uma solução. Aparentemente os navegadores (com exceção do IE) não suportam copiar outra coisa que não texto por questões de segurança. Essa thread no SO original (e as demais que ela referencia) tem explicações bastante úteis a esse respeito: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221298/copy-image-to-clipboard-not-working-in-firefox-chrome

Agora, considerando que o parâmetro 'image' que a sua callback recebe contém a URL da imagem capturada, dependendo da sua intenção (isto é, se não deseja simplesmente deixar a imagem para ser colada pelo usuário em qualquer aplicativo externo) talvez você consiga salvar a URL em um elemento html escondido ou algo assim. Ou você pode usar mesmo uma ponte em Flash como alguns usuários sugeriram na thread indicada acima. :)