# Como copiar para área de transferência em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, área-de-transferência

Qual melhor código para copiar para área de transferência que funcione em todos os navegadores?

Comment: 1)[Maneira cross-browser de copiar texto para a Área de Transferência Clipboard](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17030/91), 2)[Como copiar para área de transferência sem usar flash?] (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81098/91),
3) [Como posso copiar uma imagem para a área de transferência Clipboard?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/147/91),
4) [Como pego o que está copiado na área de transferência e coloco em uma variável?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57752/91),
5) [outras](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]area+transferencia+is%3Aquestion)

Comment: Poderia considerar minha resposta?

Comment: Não entendi? se resolveu o problema claro que a resposta é valida.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1ª Opção - Função com argumento

> Essa função é uma gambiarra que recebe um valor e automaticamente copia para a área de transferência. Caso seu navegador não suporte o tratamento de erro chama uma função secundária.

```js
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");

  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style.top = 0;
  textArea.style.left = 0;
  textArea.style.width = '2em';
  textArea.style.height = '2em';
  textArea.style.padding = 0;
  textArea.style.border = 'none';
  textArea.style.outline = 'none';
  textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';
  textArea.style.background = 'transparent';
  textArea.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    window.prompt("Copie para área de transferência: Ctrl+C e tecle Enter", text);
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}

// Teste
var copyTest = document.querySelector('.copyTest');
copyTest.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  copyTextToClipboard('Teste');
});
```

```html
<p>
  <button class="copyTest">Copiar "Teste"</button>
</p>
<p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Cole aqui">
</p>
```

Funciona nos seguintes navegadores: Chrome 43+, Firefox 41+, Internet Explorer 10+ e Opera 29+

**Notas:**

- Você pode detectar se o navegador suporta esse código utilizando:
  `var copySupported = document.queryCommandSupported('copy');`
- Todo `document.execCommand('copy')` só é chamado se o usuário efetuar
  alguma ação direta, como um evento onClick por exemplo. Isso é feito
  para evitar que dados sejam copiados para a área de transferência sem
  a intenção do usuário.

### 2ª Opção - Cópia manual via Prompt

> Nessa opção é aberto um prompt com o valor já selecionado e o usuário manualmente copia o código. A vantagem é que funciona em todos os navegadores.

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  window.prompt("Copie para área de transferência: Ctrl+C e tecle Enter", text);
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)