# Como pegar o valor "src" de uma tag "img" através de Javascript e copiá-lo para área de transferência?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera quero fazer com que quando ao clicar em cima de uma imagem, a sua url seja copiada para a área de transferência, tentei utilizar Clipboard mas apenas consegui realizar a cópia do texto.

```
var a = document.getElementById('id' + img).src.toString();
alert(a);
```

quero fazer isso mas sem o usuario ter que apertar o ctrl c, quero que seja copiada o valor quando o usuario clicar na img que chama essa funcao.

function getsrc(img) {
   var a = document.getElementById('id' + img).src.toString();
   window.prompt("Copie para área de transferência: Ctrl+C e tecle Enter", a);
}

Valor mostrado no alert : http://localhost:8084/aplicacao/2/img.jpg .
Esse valor deve ir para a area de transferencia,ao ctrl+v deve ser colado.

Com este código aparece o caminho que quero que vá para a área de transferência, mas não consigo copiá-lo para a área de transferência automaticamente quando uma `img` é clicada.

Comment: seu link não vai funcionar ederjc, pois está no localhost

Comment: é apenas um exemplo pode ser qualquer url, e funciona sim, ao copiar manualmente uma img do src ela aparece normalmente.

Comment: rsrs, quando eu disse que não vai funcionar, é quando alguém clicar aí. Isso o que você quer fazer eu tava vendo um dia desses, se eu achar a referência, posto aqui para você

Comment: O que você quer esta aqui : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89139/como-copiar-para-%C3%A1rea-de-transfer%C3%AAncia-em-javascript, [Leitura Adicional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: entendi obrigado :D

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a biblioteca `clipboard.js`, [clique aqui pra ver sua documentação](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js).

### Solução usando `clipboard.js`:

```js
// Inicia o Clipboard no elemento "button"
var copiar = new Clipboard('button', {

    // Define o texto a ser copiado
    text: function(trigger) {

        // Obtem "src" da "img" que está no mesmo nível do "button"        
        return $(trigger).siblings('img').attr('src');
    }


});

// Retorna um alert se copiar com sucesso.
copiar.on('success', function(e) {
   alert('Copiado para a area de transferencia!');
});

// Retorna um alert se copiar com erro.
copiar.on('error', function(e) {
   alert('Houve um erro ou navegador não suportado');
});
```

```html
<!-- CSS do Bootstrap, para ficar mais bonitinho :P -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- JS do Jquery e do Clipboard.js (NECESSÁRIO!) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.12/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<!-- Código com suas imagens! -->
<div class="col-xs-10 col-offset-2">
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/08/20/14/00/frog-897419_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100%">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
   COPIAR
  </button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-5">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/08/20/14/00/frog-897418_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100%">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
   COPIAR
  </button>
</div>
</div>
```

### Outros métodos de uso:

Você pode usar o `clipboard.js` de várias outras formas, não se limitando à demonstração postada, para complementar estarei postando alguns exemplos, que também estão contidos no site da documentação

**Copiar valor do `input`:**

```js
// Inicia o Clipboard no "button"
new Clipboard('button');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.12/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-xs-10">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
      <!-- Alvo a ser copiado -->
      <input id="id" class="form-control" value="Digite algo, ou clique em Copiar para copiar isso!">
  </div>
  
   <div class="col-xs-2">
      <!-- Botão para copiar -->
      <button class="btn  btn-block" data-clipboard-target="#id">
           Copiar
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nesse caso o `data-clipboard-target=""` é o responsável por copiar o valor de outro elemento, nesse caso do `input`. Assim ao clicar o usuário irá copiar o conteúdo escrito no elemento definido no `data-clipboard-target`.

**Copiar texto pre-definido no elemento:**

```js
// Inicia o Clipboard no "button"
new Clipboard('button');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.12/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-xs-10">
  <button class="btn btn-block" data-clipboard-text="Você copiou esse texto :O">
      Copiar!
  </button>
</div>
```

Nesse caso o `data-clipboard-text=""` é o responsável por definir o texto a ser copiado. Assim ao clicar o usuário irá copiar o conteúdo escrito no elemento `data-clipboard-text`.

### Compatibilidade:

> Lista de suporte oficial da biblioteca:

```
Chrome 42+
Mozilla 41+
Internet Explorer 9+
Opera 29+
```

### Licença:

**Imagens** estão sob "Public Domain":

https://pixabay.com/pt/sapo-adeus-viagens-bagagem-holdall-897420/
https://pixabay.com/pt/sapo-adeus-viagens-bagagem-holdall-897418/

**Clipboard.js** está sob "MIT License":

https://zenorocha.mit-license.org/

Answer (score 2):

Abaixo um exemplo feito com puro **Javascript**.

```js
var reply_click = function()
{
    alert("Copiado para a área de transferência");
  
  //Criando um "hidden" input
  var aux = document.createElement("input");
  
  // Atribuir-lhe o valor do elemento especificado
  aux.setAttribute("value", this.src);

  // Anexá-lo ao corpo
  document.body.appendChild(aux);

  // Highlight conteúdo
  aux.select();

  // Copiando o highlighted text
  document.execCommand("copy");

  // Removendo do corpo
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
//imagem 1
document.getElementById('1').onclick = reply_click;
//imagem 2
document.getElementById('2').onclick = reply_click;
```

```html
<img id="1" width="100" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/careers/careers-logo.png?v=c252e7f960b1"/>
<br /><br />
<img id="2" width="100" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png"/>
<br/><br/><input type="text" placeholder="Cole aqui após clicar na imagem acima" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598861/getting-the-source-of-a-specific-image-element-with-jquery) tem um exemplo que usei e funcionou.
Obs.: Utilizando somente JQuery.

```
var src = $('img[alt="example"]').attr('src');
alert("caminho da imagem = " + src);
```

Answer (score -1):

Usando jquery deve funcionar assim:

```
var imagem = $("#id-da-imagem").attr('src');
alert(imagem);
```

Comment: A partir do jQuery 1.6 a função `attr` foi substituída pela `prop` - http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Ricardo, ele está querendo copiar para a área de transferência, aí você só pegou o atributo src

Comment: ah, entendi agora

Comment: Pedro Camara, já vi casos em que attr() ainda é usado, mas de fato, prop() veio para ficar

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior não foi substituído, simplesmente juntaram um método novo para propriedades do DOM e o `.attr` é indicado para atributos do HTML.